# determination of the type of multiplication

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following question.
For one of my template classes I want too take the type of the firstly applied multiplication operator of two other types. In other words if i take two class instances and multiply them what will be resulting type.

For instance given the T, S types I want something that will determine the Q type from.

`Q operator*(T& a, S& b);`

It should work as well if the operator is the class member.

`class T{
    Q operator*(S& a);
};`

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

```
auto c = a * b;
```

Or [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
decltype(a * b);
```

Or if you don't have instances of `T` and `S`, you can use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

```
decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<S>());
```

Comment: Thanks I knew about first two but I don't have the instances and was looking for exactly the 3rd thing! Thanks a lot!